# Deploy SpringBoot 2.7.14 web application in Weblogic 12.2.1.3

Tags: weblogic12c, spring-thymeleaf, spring-boot-2

I'm trying to deploy a war to Weblogic 12.2.1.3. The application is a SpringBoot 2 web application (2.7.14).
In weblogic console I can attach war and deploy it with no issues, but when I try to access using the test link I got 404 error.
As the application is made using thymeleaf I have no index under src/main/webapp folder, I have the templates under src/main/resources/templates. I made a dummy index.html and put it on webapp folder. Now if I enter in the application I can see this dummy, but if I try to change the url to enter the login page it returns 404 again.
It seems like the servlet is not working.

My @SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer and implements WebApplicationInitializer, and still not working.

I tried to downgrade SpringBoot to 2.1.4.RELEASE and insert the javax.servlet dependency to this one:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get an alert "Overriding managed version 4.0.1 for javax.servlet-api", but the behaviour is the same.

I also made an HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

But all is working as bas as the begining. Of course the application is running fine on embeded Tomcat.

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks in advance.